# How can I check if a JS variable is a Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I need to be able to check if a variable is a buffer and I can't find any information about how to write an expression for that. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Doc for [Buffer.isBuffer()](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_isbuffer_obj).

Comment: @hhs if the below answered your question you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Buffer.isBuffer()`](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_buffer_isbuffer.asp):

```
var x = Buffer.from('abc');

console.log(Buffer.isBuffer(x));
```